# changing a link to a different link using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

how to change this URL

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/products-page/bath-and-body/">link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/bath-and-body/">link</a>
```

removing the product-page slug from wp e-commerce

so for example there is a link like this

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/products-page/bath-and-body/">link</a>
```

and it will automatically changed to this

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/bath-and-body/">link</a>
```

because I have some links that has a product-page slug and I want to get rid of it,
can this be achieved in jquery or php?

Comment: just remember that if you do it through php it will print in the source code, as it is preprocessed, and if you modify the url through jquery/javascript it will not (run time script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
$link = "http://mydomain.com/products-page/bath-and-body/";
$link = str_replace('products-page/','',$link);
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('products-page/',''));
});
```